# ORACLE SQL format

Tags: oracle

some of the headers are under each other which makes the table look weird and for some reason the "----" lines are really long which is causing this, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL*Plus you can format the columns to the width you want using the `COLUMN` command.

e.g.

```
COLUMN SP_F_NAME FORMAT A10
```

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve013.htm#SQPUG034